# Patching when changes in almost all files

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, wix, windows-installer, continuous-delivery

I'm trying to make a patch depend on git-repository because during the build we overwrite all files (this is required, change copyright note, assembly version, etc. ), and the only way that I might track the changes this is a list of the differences in git-repository   by command `git log --oneline <commit>...<commit> --name-status` and parse MSBuild project files and vs projects files to include only changed projects in there manually(ps1+xml parser), and I could not find any approaches how to parse and process this list and could not any books with the patching process, could you suggest anything about patching process or some books with MSBuild approaches

I found a solution with the WiX installer when it creates diff between 2 builds `torch -p -ax C:\patch\temp -xo rtm\install.msi upp\install.msi -out patch\diff.wixmst` but in my case, it's not working because most of  everything had changed

Comment: What is your question?  Seems to me you need to change your build/release process to support patching or don't bother with patching and just do a major upgrade.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter I told that is requirements exist when we change the source codes copy notes, versions, assembly notes for a concrete customer, but they want to makes portion updates because some licensing exists and they don't want to re-release licenses, and I'm looking for some approach for this requirements